# ¿Es posible usar VPS (servidor de Ubuntu 18.04) e instalar la interfaz y usarla remotamente solo usando ssh?

Tags: ubuntu, vps

esa es la pregunta:

¿Es posible comprar VPS (servidor de Ubuntu 18.04) e instalar la interfaz y usarla remotamente solo usando ssh?

Probé muchas cosas, instalé muchas cosas, pero nada funciona.

KDE instalado, etc ...
y he instalado XRDP para controlar remotamente pero al conectarme solo me salen puntos negros y blancos supongo que es por que se tiene que verificar desde el servidor o algo

Comment: Estás en SO en español, por favor traduce tu pregunta o eventualmente terminará cerrada

Comment: Arreglado . . .

Comment: si ya tenes el dektop instalado `apt-get install xrdp` te permite entrar por [RDP](http://www.xrdp.org/)

Comment: no funciona lo intenté solo salen puntos negros y blancos

Comment: está abierto el puerto en el firewall? `sudo ufw allow 3389` ? si no sigue enganchando puede que tengas que bindearlo a la ip publica del server ( si mal no recuerdo se engancha por default a todas las interfaces 0.0.0.0 y eso a veces da problemas )

Comment: el firewall directamente lo tengo desactivado

Comment: fijate si está corriendo `netstat -an |  grep ':3389'`

Comment: Que buena pregunta!!